# Patient, Doctor and flu vaccination

Tags: probability, self-study, bayesian

The Department of Health encourages young children to have a flu vaccination each year. The vaccination reduces the likelihood of getting a flu from 40% to 10%. If 45% of the young children visiting the doctor have the vaccination, find the probability that an young child chosen at random had the vaccination, given that he/she get flu.

Answer. How to use here bayes'theorem for finding out answer? I have to choose any one of the following:-

1)0.330

2)0.045

3)0.170

4)0.265

5)doubtful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $V$ denote presence of vaccination and $F$ denote presence of flu.

$P(V \vert F)=\frac{P(F \vert V)P(V)}{P(F \vert V)P(V)+P(F\vert \neg V)P(\neg V)}=\frac{0.1\times0.45}{0.1\times 0.45+0.4 \times0.55}$